# Показ капчи перед входом

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

У меня есть файл с капчей на Apache сервере по адресу /capcha/index.php. Как мне сделать так, чтобы при входе на сайт первый раз открывалась именно эта страница, и пока пользователь не введёт капчу, он не смог посещать другие страницы?