# Показ капчи перед входом на сайт

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Как можно организовать показ капчи перед первым входом на сайт? (кодом, пожалуйста)

Comment: Как вариант можно сделать валидацию капчи и записать результат обработки в cookie/session, и перенаправить на авторизацию где этот результат будет проверятся. Но впервые вижу чтобы так делали капчу..

Comment: Нужно именно на практике, в теории то понятно

Comment: Ну так может вы более детально раскроеете вопрос и выложите хоть код того что имеете? Здесь помогают решить задачу/вопрос, но не сделать все с нуля..

Comment: Какой именно код? Есть простой дефолтный сайт с несколькими страницами на PHP. Всё. Код страниц не играет роли.

Comment: Есть вопрос. Чем вас не устраивает к примеру hidden reCaptcha? Есть доступная документация и всем вашим запросам удовлетворяет с лихвой.

Comment: `if (нетСессии) { показатьКапчу() } else { редиректКудаТо() }`

Comment: Мне не нужно зависеть от какого-либо стороннего сервиса

Comment: Как вы пробовали?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Показ капчи перед входом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/977469/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc)

Comment: Погуглите прежде чем сюда писать http://lifeexample.ru/php-primeryi-skriptov/kapcha-na-php.htmlhttp://lifeexample.ru/php-primeryi-skriptov/kapcha-na-php.html

Comment: не дублируйте вопрос, измените предыдущий в соответствии с рекомендациями и подайте заявку на переоткрытие

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Погуглите прежде чем сюда писать http://lifeexample.ru/php-primeryi-skriptov/kapcha-na-php.html

> А так вот пример с сайта:

```
Нужно запилить 5 файлов:

    index.php – скрипт выводящий нашу капчу на PHP;
    validator.php – скрипт проверяющий сходство с картинкой;
    capcha.php – скрипт генерирующий картинку;
    comic.ttf – шрифт текста;
    bg_capcha.png – фон под текстом.
```

> index.php

```
Введите код с картинки:
<br/>
 <img style="border: 1px solid gray; background: url('bg_capcha.png');" src = "captcha.php" width="120" height="40"/>
<br/>
<form action="validator.php" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="capcha" />
     <input type="submit" name="send" value="Проверить"/>
</form>
```

> capcha.php

```
  $letters = 'ABCDEFGKIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'; // алфавит

  $caplen = 6; //длина текста
  $width = 120; $height = 40; //ширина и высота картинки
  $font = 'comic.ttf';//шрифт текста
  $fontsize = 14;// размер текста

  header('Content-type: image/png'); //тип возвращаемого содержимого (картинка в формате PNG) 

  $im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); //создаёт новое изображение
  imagesavealpha($im, true); //устанавливает прозрачность изображения
  $bg = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 127); //идентификатор цвета для изображения
  imagefill($im, 0, 0, $bg); //выполняет заливку цветом

  putenv( 'GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.') ); //проверяет путь до файла со шрифтами

  $captcha = '';//обнуляем текст
  for ($i = 0; $i < $caplen; $i++)
  {
    $captcha .= $letters[ rand(0, strlen($letters)-1) ]; // дописываем случайный символ из алфавила 
    $x = ($width - 20) / $caplen * $i + 10;//растояние между символами
    $x = rand($x, $x+4);//случайное смещение
    $y = $height - ( ($height - $fontsize) / 2 ); // координата Y
    $curcolor = imagecolorallocate( $im, rand(0, 100), rand(0, 100), rand(0, 100) );//цвет для текущей буквы
    $angle = rand(-25, 25);//случайный угол наклона 
    imagettftext($im, $fontsize, $angle, $x, $y, $curcolor, $font, $captcha[$i]); //вывод текста
  }

  // открываем сессию для сохранения сгенерированного текста
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['capcha'] = $captcha;

  imagepng($im); //выводим изображение
  imagedestroy($im);//отчищаем память
```

> validator.php

```
session_start();
if($_POST['capcha'] != $_SESSION['capcha']) 
    echo "Текст с картинки введен не верно!";
else
    echo "Ура текст совпал!";
```